# If auto number field then skip copying this

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have got some vbscript that copies row's from one sheet to another, adjusting edits and adding new rows.

This works fine until it reaches a table that has an auto number column, when trying to copy say a value of "7" into the auto number where it wants to add "10" its clearly not going to work.

So I am trying to have it not try and copy this field from the previous database and instead let it auto populate that value and copy the rest. Here is my code:

```
Public Function update6()

    'Temp field
    Dim fField As Field
    Dim bCopy As Boolean

    'Open source database
    Dim dSource As Database
    Set dSource = CurrentDb

    'Open dest database
    Dim dDest As Database
    Set dDest = DAO.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\BMcDoanld\Documents\SellerDeck 2013\Sites\Site1\ActinicCatalog.mdb")

    'Open source recordset
    Dim rSource As Recordset
    Set rSource = dSource.OpenRecordset("OrderMail", dbOpenForwardOnly)

    'Open dest recordset
    Dim rDest As Recordset
    Set rDest = dDest.OpenRecordset("OrderMail", dbOpenDynaset)

    'Loop through source recordset
    While Not rSource.EOF

        'Reset copy flag
        bCopy = False

        'Look for record in dest recordset
        rDest.FindFirst "nMailID = " & rSource.Fields("nMailID") & ""

        If rDest.NoMatch Then

           'If not found, copy record
            rDest.AddNew
            bCopy = True
        Else

            'If found, check for differences
            For Each fField In rSource.Fields
                If rDest.Fields(fField.Name) <> rSource.Fields(fField.Name) Then
                    rDest.Edit
                    bCopy = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next fField
            Set fField = Nothing
        End If

        'If copy flag is set, copy record
        If bCopy Then

            For Each fField In rSource.Fields
            rDest.Fields(fField.Name) = rSource.Fields(fField.Name)
            Next fField
            Set fField = Nothing

            rDest.Update
        End If

        'Next source record
        rSource.MoveNext
    Wend

    'Close dest recordset
    rDest.Close
    Set rDest = Nothing

    'Close source recordset
    rSource.Close
    Set rSource = Nothing

    'Close dest database
    dDest.Close
    Set dDest = Nothing

    'Close source database
    dSource.Close
    Set dSource = Nothing

End Function
```

The line I am getting an error on is:

```
'If copy flag is set, copy record
If bCopy Then

    For Each fField In rSource.Fields
    rDest.Fields(fField.Name) = rSource.Fields(fField.Name)
    Next fField
    Set fField = Nothing

    rDest.Update
End If
```

I have been playing around with detecting the property but I am getting an invalid property error with this following code:

```
    For Each fField In rSource.Fields
    If rDest.Fields(fField.Name).Properties("ISAUTOINCREMENT") = True Then
            rDest.Fields(fField.Name) = rSource.Fields(fField.Name)
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the field's `Attributes` property.  For an autonumber field, `(Attributes And dbAutoIncrField) = dbAutoIncrField`.

Since you want to update all the fields except the autonumber, limit to those those fields where `<> dbAutoIncrField`.

```vb
For Each fField In rSource.Fields
    If (fField.Attributes And dbAutoIncrField) <> dbAutoIncrField Then
        rDest.Fields(fField.Name) = rSource.Fields(fField.Name)
    End If
Next fField
```